# Resharper code cleanup not available on Unityconfig.cs

Tags: c#, resharper, code-cleanup

I'm using `ReSharper 2016.3.2`. It works nicely, but I bumped into a weird issue, the `code cleanup` feature is not available for `UnityConfig.cs`. The `Refactor` context menu is disabled, the hotkey for cleanup shows the following message:

> The Key combination (Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C) is bound to command (ReSharper_CleanupCode) which is not currently available.

I looked into ReSharper settings, the `Elements to skip` blocks are empty, where they're present (Search & navigation, Code inspection settings).

If I rename the file, cleanup option works normally. For other `...Config.cs` files the cleanup option also works normally, so it seems like this particular filename is ignored.

My question is: where can I disable this behavior?

**update**

The file is used to configure the DI container, which comes from [Unity Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/).

The content is quite simple, here's a skeleton:

```
public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration httpConfig)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    //register components

    var unityServiceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => unityServiceLocator);
    httpConfig.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details of what `UnityConfig.cs` is? What's in the file, where does it live, does it come from a NuGet package?

Comment: @citizenmatt I updated the question with more details

Comment: @Szeki It looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-371787, when a file came from a nuget package. So try removing "Unity" record from packages.config file

Answer (score 3):

This is because the code comes from a nuget package. ReSharper will disable analysis and other features in code that is part of a nuget package because the idea is it's not user code - it's 3rd party, written by someone else, so ReSharper shouldn't apply your styles to it. Also, I'm not sure, but I think the file might get overwritten if the nuget package is updated.

Comment: Unity is indeed a NuGet, but the file to configure it didn't come by adding that package. `UnityConfig.cs` was created by me.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's being marked as disabled, unless there is a package that happens to have a content file of the same name. Either way, you should be able to right click the status icon in the scrollbar and resume analysis.

Comment: @citizenmatt What do you mean by "icon in the scrollbar"?

Comment: ReSharper adds an icon to the top of the scrollbar in documents that it analyses, top right of the editor window. This is a green tick, or yellow exclamation or red error symbol. Or, if the file isn't being analysed, a pause symbol. Right clicking on the icon brings up a menu that allows control, such as pausing or resuming analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I Restarted visual studio and it solved the issue.