# ReSharper cleanup not available in Xamarin projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, resharper

I'm using ReSharper Ultimate version 2017.1.2 in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and I experience problems regarding the cleanup. As for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440003/resharper-code-cleanup-not-available-on-unityconfig-cs) post states out, ReSharper will disable cleanup under certain conditions.

In my case the cleanup is completely disabled if there is at least one Xamarin-based project loaded in the solution. So lets say my solution looks like this:

```
Solution1
   + ProjectA (.NET DLL)
   + ProjectB (Xamarin.iOS)
   + Proect C (.NET DLL)
```

In this case ReSharper Cleanup will not be available in any of the files. If I now create a new solution file which will omit "ProjectB":

```
Solution2
   + ProjectA (.NET DLL)
   + Proect C (.NET DLL)
```

everything just works as expected.

This means I cannot cleanup my Xamarin stuff currently which was possible in the past I'm pretty sure. Does anyone now how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Visual Studio updated to version `15.2 (26430.6)` the bevavior disappeared.